# How to change fillColor of a textfield while typing in that textfield?

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat, custom-formatting

i want to change the fillColor of a textfield while typing in it.

The field is empty and the fillColor is red for default.
How to change the fillColor to transparent while typing in this field, so before leaving it?

Thanks.

Edit: Im using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC.

my code in custom keystroke script:

```
var a = this.getField("a");
if(event.value == 0){
a.fillColor = color.red;
}else{
a.fillColor = color.transparent;
};
```

but this changes the color after leaving the textfield.
How to change that code to change the color before leaving the textfield?

Comment: are you tried yet? share your tried code.

Comment: @SavadKP i edited my question with sample code that i tried.

Comment: It's unclear what event your code is using. The "focus" and "blur" events (actions) are the ones you need to use.

Comment: You can try fiddling with the Keystroke event. You address the field with event.target, and you may work with event.change and/or event.changeEx. See Acrobat JavaScript documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Javascript within Actions in the field properties on field activation, using:

```
event.target.fillColor = color.yellow;
```

Then the background will become yellow as soon as you click into the field. And revert to the light blue (default) when you leave the field.